# Web application in worklight 8.0

Tags: web-applications, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

I have followed document and created web application and also register application in mobile first console. Developer guide is here:

http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/development/web/
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/web/#registering-the-web-application

i have few queries,

1. where I can deploy .war in console?
2. where i can find public url of my web application?
3. where I can deploy web resource?
4. While create web application I used Maven, in Maven web application where I can server url and port?

Answer (score 0):

In IBM MobileFirst 8.0, MobileFirst server does not host the web application. The web application will be hosted in a webserver or Liberty Application Server or as a Node application etc - basically, hosted outside of MobileFirst server.

The web application will embed MobileFirst web SDK and direct the requests to MobileFirst Server.It can use a proxy for this.

To answer the questions:

1. Where I can deploy .war in console?

   The .war can be deployed in the same server as MobileFirst server or can be hosted separately. The web application war file is not deployed into MobileFirst server or via MobileFirst server. It is performed independently.
2. Where i can find public url of my web application?

   This will depend on where you host the web application and expose it.
3. Where I can deploy web resource?

   In your web application and the server where you host it.
4. While create web application I used maven, In maven web application
   where I can server url and port?

   Assuming you are referring to creating a Maven webapp and deploying it to Liberty server, the URL will be of type "http(s)://{application server host}:{app server port}/{context root of web application}"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got some more queries, 1. Do I need to host complete web application code in my application server? 2. http(s)://application server host:port/context/my application name/client/index.html is this my public url of my application?

Comment: 4. I have created maven web application and trying to deploy .war file in normal application server. Is this right process? 5. server.xml is not part of web application. It is in /Users/ban82779/MobileFirst-8.0.0.0/mfp-server/usr/servers/mfp/server.xml. So add .war file path in this file.Is this correct file?

Comment: Your complete webapplication needs to be hosted. And server.xml is the server configuration for a Liberty server. You should add your war file to Liberty server and ensure its entry appears in server.xml for it to be hosted:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=deploying-applications-in-liberty

Comment: I have created war file and deploying it in WebSphere. Now my question is, in developer guide I did't find where we need set mfpserver configation details In maven web application?. Please help me Vivin.